# Have a function with generic return a function with same generic

Tags: typescript

For example, I want the following function to return a function that accepts any string or any number, depending on what the initial function was called with, but it only accepts strings or numbers that are equal to `a`:

```
function foo<A extends string | number>(a: A) : (b: A) => boolean {
  return (b) => a === b;
}

foo("test") // creates a function that only accepts "test", want one that accepts any string.
foo(3) // creates a function that only accepts 3, want one that accepts any number.
```

How do I type this function so it works as wanted?

- edited to clarify what the problem is

Comment: This feels backwards of generics. Why would "`A extends string`" mean "any `string`"? It means the opposite of that (a constraint on string). Is there another example of what you would want to accept and reject?

Comment: `A extends string` puts a constraint on the type A that it must also be a string, it doesn't put a constraint on string.

Comment: It feels like maybe we're reading your desire backwards of what you mean? The above code does create a function that only accepts `"test"` (since that's what you asked for). And if you want to to accept any `string`, then the function in my answer does that (no need for generics at all). I'm not sure where `number` comes into this. Are you happy that `foo(3)` returns a function that only accepts `3` or do you mean you want it to accept all numbers because it was passed a "number-like value?"

Comment: If you want "return a function that requires something of the type of the value I passed," then MacD's answer is exactly what you want. What do you mean by "lose the type information?"

Comment: "accepts any string or any number" and "only accepts strings or numbers that are equal to `a`" are opposite statements. Which do you mean?

Comment: Because I want the function to be typed such that it only accepts strings or numbers. MacD's answer has no such type information. The question has been updated if you still don't understand.

Comment: MacD's answer does return a function that only accepts strings or numbers depending on what's passed to it.

Comment: ""accepts any string or any number" and "only accepts strings or numbers that are equal to a" are opposite statements. Which do you mean? – Rob Napier 50 secs ago"

I want it to accept any string or number, but it only accepts a string or number that is equal to the initial argument `a`. I'm not sure what you are confused about.

Comment: "Any string" is the opposite of "only strings equal to `a`". I'm really suspecting that MacD's answer is exactly what you want here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220639/discussion-between-theo-sherry-and-rob-napier).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just remove the `extends string` it seems to do what you want

```
function foo<A>(a: A) : (b: A) => boolean {
  return (b) => a === b;
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8BBAfACgIYBciGAlIkTgEZGmIC8WilqANgKZ5IDeAUIogCc2UEAKRUyDRHnp06TANw8Avjx4o4OAERQ2AZyhaS2vUf4B6c2wAeABzbQ9iAwJhgA5utQ4AjMYBMZIiWNvaOiGAgALaUbAJAA)

If you want to restrict your input types and still have them pass through you could do the following

```
function foo(a:string): (b:string) => boolean
function foo(a:number): (b:number) => boolean
function foo(a:boolean): (b:boolean) => boolean

function foo (a: string|number|boolean) : (b: string|number|boolean) => boolean {
  return (b) => a === b;
}

foo("test")("a")  //expects string
foo(1)(2)  //expects number
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBDAXAZygJxjAHMBKLRNAI1wKLMQF4A+RK1AGwFMMwAoUJFgJkqTFjAgAtlS75ylGpJlzSTVuzjdeA8NHhIU6bJu1gF1LKZ7n1bTjb66hB0XErZEeQiQA+y2Xxfa141CksvOj8AuWCHULsQpABvPkREfC4oEHwkajUWRAwmRkY2AG4+AF8nIzQAIiguPHrSBoxW9IB6Lq4ADwAHLmgcSJ9iATEARjaAJjVEHv6hkcQY-D4gA)

Comment: You lose the type information of the initial argument though, which I want to keep.

Comment: In my case the function returned by foo("test") expects a string and foo(1) expects a number as the argument, from your question that was my understanding of what you wanted. I've added a link with the solution.

Comment: "You lose the type information of the initial argument though, which I want to keep." But you seem to want to get rid of it. The type of the argument is `"test"`. That's it's type and that's what the returned function accepts. But you want a particular super-type (`string`) instead?

Answer (score -1):

It seems the way to do this is using overloads:

```
function foo(a1: number): (a2: number) => boolean; 
function foo(a1: string): (a1: string) => boolean;
function foo(a1: number | string): (a2: number|string) => boolean {
  return (a2) => a1 === a2;
}
```

Comment: @ritaj You need to read the chat. Theo's question isn't actually what is in the question. (I agree that MacD's answer is the most generic solution and a good one.)

Comment: This is the same solution as MacD's updated and accepted answer. Thanks MacD!

Comment: Ah; MacD had updated while we chatted. Excellent answer.